# Flutter error: _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, ItemStatus>

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serialization, json-serializable, json-annotation

I am using `json_annotation` to generate the `fromJson` and `toJson` functions for my custom class `ItemStatus`:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part 'item.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true, anyMap: true)
class ItemStatus {
  final String id;
  int vote = 0;
  bool saved = false;
  bool postRead = false;
  bool articleRead = false;

  ItemStatus({required this.id});

  //generate using: flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
  factory ItemStatus.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ItemStatusFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ItemStatusToJson(this);
}
```

The encoding works fine however when I try to decode it back to `ItemStatus`, it throws an error:

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'ItemStatus'
```

Here's me trying to do the encoding and decoding:

```
try {
      final itemStatus = ItemStatus(id: "abcd123");
      itemStatus.saved = true;

      final jsonString = jsonEncode(itemStatus);
      print("jsonString: $jsonString");

      ItemStatus decoded = jsonDecode(jsonString);
      print("decoded: $decoded");
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `decode` an object. You need to use `toJson` and `fromJson` like this:

```
final jsonString = jsonEncode(ItemStatus. toJson(itemStatus));
print("jsonString: $jsonString");
```

and decode it like this:

```
ItemStatus decoded = ItemStatus.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonString));
print("decoded: $decoded");
```